# How to deduce the shape of autocorrelation graphically?

Tags: autocorrelation

I'm asking for your help in understanding if I have a rectangular function, so the autocorrelation for it will be triangular... and I can prove that graphically but this is time-consuming especially if I have another complicated signal...

**So is there any way to know how to deduce quickly the graphic shape of the autocorrelation of any signal**?

Comment: You could use Matlab or similar languages to get a quick numerical estimate...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem that I'm afraid that complex function comes at the exam

Comment: Then your best bet is to practice a lot with the most complex functions you can come up with... there are no shortcuts. As you practice, try to develop your intuition of how a result "should look like"; this will help you catch errors quickly.